# Calculate number of cells in row above threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
Student_ID | Year | Math Grade | English Grade
----------------------------------------------
1          | 2009 | 90         | 92

2          | 2009 | 80         | 95

1          | 2010 | 75         | 85
```

I want to calculate the number grades a student got each year over 90. The desired output for the above table is:

```
Student_ID | Year | Math Grade | English Grade | Grades Above 90
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2009 | 91         | 92            | 2

2          | 2009 | 80         | 95            | 1

1          | 2010 | 75         | 85            | 0
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any control over the table structure? normalising it would be beneficial.    You say in another question that you have this table in a normalised format, that would be much easier to work with.  I'm going to assume this is a homework question, so please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions (sorry if I guessed wrong, but teachers do like setting questions based on student data!)

Comment: @JeffUK Thanks, but I figured it out right after I posted the question! See my answer below if you're interested. Also, I'm not a student, I am actually working for a school doing data analytics for them!

Comment: ... I don't understand why you wouldn't do this operation on the normalised table if you have that available to you.  It would be a simple grouping operation. and would automatically extend to any subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a pretty simple solution for this. I added to the end of my SELECT statement:
    SELECT math_grade/90 + english_grade/90 AS grades_above_90

Comment: This is not a safe solution because it does not work if the threshold is less than 50.  I strongly recommend using `case`.

Comment: That gives 2.033333, 1.9444 and 1.7777

Comment: @JeffUK Its integer division so any grade under 90 when divided by 90 should return 0

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you explain the problem with a threshold less than 50 to me?

Comment: "How many students got a grade over 40" would give you erroneous results for anyone with a score over 80, (would count each grade over 80 twice).

Comment: @ZachB . . . Is there a reason why the other solution did not work?  I'm surprised you unaccepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this using a `case` statement:

```
select ((math_grade > 90 then 1 else 0 end) + (english_grade > 90 then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as grades_above_90
```

The problem with using division is that it doesn't work if the threshold is less than 50.